# Most pythonic/stylish/efficient way to create a dataframe from 2-dimensional list of string with varied length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I guess professional data analysts know an answer to this, but I'm no analyst.
And I just barely know Pandas. So I am at a loss.

There are two lists. Their contents are unpredictable (parsed from web counters, web analytics, web statistics, etc).

```py
list1 = ['WordA', 'WordB', ..., 'WordXYZ']
```

...and...

```
list2 = [['WordA1', 'WordA2'], ['WordB1'], ['WordC1', 'WordC2', ,'WordC96'], ..., ['WordXYZ1', 'WordXYZ2']]
```

Length of two lists are always equal (they`re the results of work of parser I already wrote)

What I need is to create a dataframe which will have **two** rows for each item in `list1`, each containing the word in first column, and then put corresponding words from `list2` into **first** row of those two (starting from second column, first column to bealready filled from `list1`).

So I imagine the following steps:

1. Create a dataframe filled with empty strings ('') with number of columns equal to `len(max(list2, key=len))` and number of rows equal to **twice** length of `list1` (*aaaand I don't know how, this is actually my very second time using Pandas at all!*);
2. Somehow fill first column of resulting dataframe with contents of `list1`, filling two rows for each item in `list1`;
3. Somehow put contents of `list2` into every even row of the dataframe, starting with second column;
4. Save into .xls file (*yes, that's the final goal*), enjoy job done.

Now first thing, I already spend half a day trying to find an answer "**how to create pandas dataframe filled with empty strings with given number of rows and columns**", and found a lot of different articles, which contradict each other.

And second, there's got to be a way to do all this more pythonic, more efficient and more stylish way!

*Aaaand*, maybe there`s a way to create an excel file without using pandas at all, which I just don't know about (*hopefully, yet*)

Can anyone help, please?

UPD: (to answer a question) the results should look like:

```
WordA WordA1 WordA2 
WordA 
WordB WordB1 
WordB 
WordC WordC1 WordC2 (...) WordC96 
WordC 
(...)x2 
WordXYZ WordXYZ1 WordXYZ2 
WordXYZ
```

Comment: Can you add the expected output for your almost complete input?

Comment: something like:
```
WordA  WordA1  WordA2
WordA
WordB  WordB1
WordB
WordC  WordC1  WordC2 (...)  WordC96
WordC
(...) *2
WordXYZ  WordXYZ1  WordXYZ2
WordXYZ
```

UPD: *beep* how do I format a comment?...

Comment: Add it in the question please

Comment: ...done that just now!

Comment: I guess it's better to write the lists directly to Excel (using for instance [`xlsxwriter`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) or [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) than taking the detour of pandas just to be able to use `to_excel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to write the lists to an Excel file, you don't need pandas. You can use for instance [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for *word, words in zip(list1, list2):
    ws.append(word + words)
    ws.append(word)

wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

---

If you really want to use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[None] + x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for pair in zip(list2, list1) for x in pair])
df[0] = df[0].bfill() 
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for information on existence of `openpyxl`!
It's not that I *want* to use pandas, it's that I happened to always use in to create .xls files if I ever needed to create one. Never needed anything else. Not that I create them often...
And It works now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The following should give you (almost) what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

list1 = ['WordA', 'WordB']
list2 = [['WordA1', 'WordA2'], ['WordB1']]

# Flatten list 2
list2 = list(chain(*list2))

# Create DataFrames
list1 = pd.DataFrame(data=list1, columns=["word1"])
list2 = pd.DataFrame(data=list2, columns=["word2"])

# Prefix for list2
list2["prefix"] = list2["word2"].str.extract("([^0-9]+)")

list1 = list1.merge(list2, left_on="word1", right_on="prefix", how="inner")

# Concatenated words
list1 = list1.groupby("word1")["word2"].agg(lambda x: " ".join(x)).reset_index()
list1["word2"] = list1["word1"].str.cat(list1["word2"], sep=" ")
list1 = pd.melt(list1).sort_values(by="value")
```

Comment: Wow.
That's actually reverses order of actions -- first make all sublists of same size, then create a dataframe of them.
Didn't think of that, thank you!